# Fail to send smtp mail poco c++

Tags: c++, smtp, gmail, poco

I am new to c++ and tring to send a mail using gmail smtp. I have done this in python but I  am unable to do it in c++. I think I need to add **startTLS()** but it seems to be not defined. Please help me, I have tried my best. Searched the internet also could not find any thing.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <Poco/Net/SMTPClientSession.h>
#include <Poco/Net/MailMessage.h>
#include <string>

using namespace Poco::Net;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string Username = "farhantestingsmtp@gmail.com";
    std::string Password = "cpguxktxoyibiybd";
    
    std::string Receiver = "jattfarhan10@gmail.com";
    std::string Name = "Jatt Farhan";

    std::string Subject = "Hello!";
    std::string Content = "TEXT OF THE EMAIL";

    try
    {
        MailMessage msg;

        msg.addRecipient(MailRecipient(MailRecipient::PRIMARY_RECIPIENT, Receiver, Name));

        msg.setSender(Username);
        msg.setSubject(Subject);
        msg.setContent(Content);
        SMTPClientSession smtp("smtp.gmail.com", 487);
        smtp.open();
        cout << "Before Login";
        smtp.login(SMTPClientSession::AUTH_LOGIN, Username, Password);

        cout << "After Login";
        smtp.sendMessage(msg);
        smtp.close();
        std::cerr << "Sent mail successfully!" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to send mail: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have added my mail username and password, as it for testing. Thanks in advance.

I tried to add startTLS and could not do it as The SecureSMTPClientSession was not defined in my VS environment. I also searched the internet, but could not fix it.

Comment: 487 is not a valid Gmail SMTP port.  The valid choices are 25, 465 (implicit ssl), and 587 (explicit tls).  The `STARTTLS` command works on port 587.  Poco implements support for that command via [`SecureSMTPClientSession`](https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/Poco.Net.SecureSMTPClientSession.html), as you noted. The fact that your VS environment doesn't know what `SecureSMTPClientSession` is likely means either 1) you are using an outdated version of Poco and should upgrade to the latest version, or 2) you have not configured your environment correctly.

Comment: What is the full error message

Comment: I used 487 because I was using the same in Python script and it worked. I have installed poco from vcpkg. I do not know if it is older distribution. I will check it and update you soon

Comment: I rechecked, I was using 587. But changing to 587 also not worked with startTLS, I must be doing doing some thing wrong. Now I am using port 465 and it is working like charm. Thanks for you advice.